# Why does contentedible div with truncation add whitespace in Chrome when constrained

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, word-wrap, contenteditable

So I have a setup like this:

```html
<div style="width:130px; background-color:lime">
   <div contentEditable style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
      Hi I am a long piece of text, well sort of long lalalaa
    </div>
</div>
```

At first this seems to work correctly but after I start typing more text than fits, it just adds whitespace and moves the ellipsis left. I am not sure what is causing this or how to make the caret move right with the text.

[image: Example of problem]

Comment: Seems like a temporary browser bug of some kind. The Snippet I just converted your code to shows no issue in Firefox. What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome. I just checked and agree it works as expected in firefox.

Comment: This seems to be related to the object being scrolled internally (if you add the div to your console and set `.scrollLeft = 0` it behaves as you expected). `overflow: hidden` does not mean there is no overflow that can be scrolled, and you can still programatically scroll it. Since there's no wrapping here due to CSS, the browser is probably trying to `scrollIntoView` the carret position, creating this effect. A debounced event listener could potentially help here?

Comment: Adding `oninput="setTimeout(() => this.scrollLeft = 0,1)"` sort-of fixes it but this does not behave nicely (it works but it looks kinda jumpy). Personally, if the user can enter content you should probably show it or truncate it yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Chrome cannot correctly display the combination of the `contentEditable` feature and the `text-overflow: ellipsis;` attribute. One approach would be to remove ellipsis if the focus is on it.

(Credits to @somethinghere for the addition `onblur="this.scrollLeft = 0"`)

```css
[contentEditable]:focus {
  text-overflow: initial !important;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:130px; background-color:lime">
   <div contentEditable onblur="this.scrollLeft = 0" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
      Hi I am a long piece of text, well sort of long lalalaa
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This still leave the text of screen when the input is blurred. Maybe add `onblur="this.scrollLeft = 0"` to prevent that?

Comment: Just noticed that introduces the issue of returning the carret to the end when it is focused :D. That should be possible on focus, but its a little unwieldier to move the carret back to the end in the code...

Comment: This approach best got me where I needed. Thanks to all for solid input.

Answer (score 1):

Change your width to 100%,
Remove the overflow,
And set the white space to wrap

```html
<div style="width: 100%; background-color:lime">
   <div contentEditable style=" white-space: wrap;">
      Hi I am a long piece of text, well sort of long lalalaa
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So basically "damn your question, just do something entirely different?"

Comment: @somethinghere Workarounds are acceptable solutions to problems on Stack Overflow. It's up to OP to specify whether a workaround is acceptable or if it violates the constraints they have.